# putting a border around a complex shape i photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the image below:

[image]

I am trying to put a border around the brownish area, the image has the white snowflakes merging into the white background, so i can't just select it in a simple way, what is the best method to select the image and put a border around the outside of the shape?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to select the snowflakes and then put a border around it?

Comment: I am trying to select the pinky brown area with the torn looking ends, which would include the snow flakes, but also the pinky brown background. the problem is , I can't just use the magic wand on the white and invert selection, because it won't select the snowflakes. I hope this makes sense,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Quick selection tool. It learns as you subtract some extras from the selection by holding Alt as you select and add some missing pars by holding Shift as you select.

After that you can smooth the edge to straighten exessive wrinkles, if needed. Unfortunately it makes some sharp corners round, but you can add them back to the selection with the Polygonal lasso tool (+ holding Shift for add or Alt for subtract). Here's an example of the resulted selection:

[image]

Save the selection. You probably need it for masking or conversion to a path. I would add the border by clipping the pattern to another layer and then I would add below it a filled area which is created by expanding the selection few pixels and then painting it full. Here's an example:

[image]